# I am not able to copy files into remote computer

Tags: 12.04, windows, remmina

I am using ubunt 12.04 LTS. I connected to Windows 2008 server through Remmina Remote Desktop Client. I am not able to copy files from my system to client system.

Comment: What happens when you try? Feel free to edit your question to add more information.

Comment: When i try it, in windows 2008 if i right click the  mouse - paste is not highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to transfer files between computer was to access your ubuntu computer by ssh from the windows computer.

To do this you can install in the windows computer winSCP or some similar software and use it to connect to your computer ip.

Remember that you must have port 22 open and you can use `ifconfig` to find out what is your IP.